# send data from a C# asp.net web site to an installed C# windows forms app

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm working on a net based POS system and need to enable silent printing. 
(Print without displaying the PrintDialog).

I have managed to get it working but at times when cashiers want to generate new vouchers it does not print and this is becoming a problem.

I have been instructed to create a Windows Forms app that will be installed on all of my cashiers machines, what this app needs to do is once the cashiers log onto the website and sells a voucher i need data to be sent from my ASP.NET website to the Windows form application where the silent print can take place, so as soon as the cashiers clicks on the 'Sell Voucher' button the data must be sent to the installed windows app and print automatically.

The data that will be sent to the cashiers machines is basic info like Cashier Name, Account Name, Site...etc

How would i go about achieving this result?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To get a more detailed answer to this question, provide information on what you've tried/researched so far.

Answer (score 2):

The two apps will probably need to share a single data source (e.g. using SQL Server).

If the printing needs to happen silently, without user intervention, then you will need to implement a listener (typically as a Windows Service) that waits for new items to be added and are ready to print.

See: [Publish-subscribe pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) or, alternatively, [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Look into [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) or [signalr.net](http://signalr.net/)

for signalR there is a .net client for easy implementation into a windows app